# Orange Pi Zero & MFRC522 Application

Tags: python, rfid, orange-pi

I want to build a project to read Mifare cards via orange pi zero. I have `MFRC522` module and the connections are like

```
SDA ------> PIN 24
SCK ------> PIN 22
MOSI -----> PIN 19
MISO -----> PIN 21
IRQ ------> **NONE**
GND ------> PIN 6
RST ------> PIN 22
3.3V -----> PIN 1
```

Until now, not a single problem I have. I googled a little bit, and find out some advices. Afterwards I did these steps on my orangepi zero.

By the way I'm using **ARMBIAN 5.31** stable Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS 3.4.113-sun8i

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-dev
sudo git clone https:/github.com/duxingkei33/orangepi_PC_gpio_pyH3.git
cd orangepi_PC_gpio_pyH3
sudo python setup.py install
cd ..
sudo git clone https://github.com/lthiery/SPI-Py.git
cd SPI-Py
sudo python setup.py install
cd ..
sudo git clone https://github.com/mxgxw/MFRC522-python.git
cd MFRC522-python
```

Until here, there is still not a single problem. Now, here we go.

1. One of these advices say

Now its time to edit MFRC522.py. I am providing the diff with the original.

```
 import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
 110c110
 < def init(self, dev='/dev/spidev1.0', spd=1000000):

 def init(self, dev='/dev/spidev0.0', spd=1000000):
 112,114c112,114
 <# GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
 < # GPIO.setup(22, GPIO.OUT)
 < # GPIO.output(self.NRSTPD, 1)

 GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
 GPIO.setup(22, GPIO.OUT)
 GPIO.output(self.NRSTPD, 1)
```

2. And the other says

7)To read id data:

```
cd MFRC522-python
edit  MFRC522.py and comment out line 108.109.110  and 356( as shown below)
      # GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
      #GPIO.setup(22, GPIO.OUT)
      #GPIO.output(self.NRSTPD, 1)

       #GPIO.output(self.NRSTPD, 1)

    python read.py

 root@orangepione:~/MFRC522-python# python read.py
```

Whatever I do, still I have errors. Second one says "not such a file", first one I dont even understand what to do. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

I also had this same problem. I discovered that for some reason the drive to spi was not loading. Even using armbian-config.

Verify that the device exists by using:

```
ls /dev/spi*
```

In my case it did not exist.

I had to make the following changes manually:
in the /boot/armbianEnv.txt file, add (or edit) the lines (using sudo nano /boot/armbianEnv.txt):

```
overlay_prefix = sun8i-h3
overlays = spi-spidev cir i2c0 uart1 w1-gpio
param_spidev_spi_bus = 0
param_spidev_max_freq = 100000000
```

Then add the line to the /etc/modules file (using sudo nano /etc/modules):
    spi-dev

Restart the system.

In my case, python needs root access to read / write data on the SPI bus. So I have to run the program using sudo python Dump.py, for example.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is a bit late ...

`diff`is a linux program that computes the differences between two files :

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff_utility

this is like in wikipedia when you see the difference between two versions

In `MFRC522.py` you have to comment out ( adding `#` which marks a comment in the code so that it is not compiled )  in lines 112,113,114 and 384

of https://github.com/mxgxw/MFRC522-python/blob/master/MFRC522.py ( version of 01.10.2017 )

you can not use `RPi.GPIO` on OrangePi, maybe see http://opi-gpio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html and http://www.instructables.com/id/Orange-Pi-One-Python-GPIO-basic/